# Cannot post value to database Using API post method and postman

Tags: c#, json, linq, api

I have an API method to insert data to database, but when ever I tried to test it with postman, its returning bad request, Here is my code

```
private Utilities uti = new Utilities();
private readonly ApplicationDBContext db;
public AppraisalController(ApplicationDBContext context)
{
    db = context;
}
//INSERT API FOR AppraisalIdentity table
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/appraiseinsert")]
[HttpPost]

public IActionResult Create([FromBody] AppraisalIdentity cre)
{
    if (cre == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            #region Appraisal Insert
            var apprais = new AppraisalIdentity
            {
                AppraisalName = cre.AppraisalName,
                IsCurrent = cre.IsCurrent,
                CompanyID = cre.CompanyID
            };
            db.AppraisalIdentity.Add(apprais);
            db.SaveChanges();
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            return Json(new
            {
                statusCode = ex.Message
            });
        }

    }

    return Json(new
    {
        statusCode = "Success"
    });
}
```

whenever I try testing it on postman man
first of all.... If I try using json, it will be returning "bad string". I don't know if the fault is from the api or from my json method of inserting values.... Here the json format am using

```
{
“AppraisalName” : “Appraisal Name”,
“IsCurrent”: 1,
“CompanyID”: 2
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the symbol of '”'? I think the correct of Json string is:

```
{
   "AppraisalName" : "Harish",
   "IsCurrent": 1,
   "CompanyID": 2
}
```

Comment: Yes, it appears OP was using some other, invalid, double quote character.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, am no more getting bad request.... Its Success now.... Thanks

Comment: the problem was the quotation marks... but its resolved now